# How to load a texture with GL Image?

Tags: opengl

I know how to load the texture

```
std::unique_ptr<glimg::ImageSet> pImgSet(glimg::loaders::dds::LoadFromFile("test.dds"));
GLuint tex = glimg::CreateTexture(pImgSet.get(), 0);
```

But how do I get this texture into my shader?
[GL Image - Unoffcial OpenGL SDK](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glimg.html)

Comment: That's not plain OpenGL. What framework/library are you using?

Comment: @Thomas: [This one.](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html) It's also just texture loading code; it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: "*But how do I get this texture into my shader?*" [The same way you do for any other OpenGL texture.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29) GL Image just loads the texture for you; how you *use it* is up to you.

Comment: Okay thanks, I just was confused I read some code examples about loading textures and it completely confused me. For example http://open.gl/content/code/c3_basic.txt He uses a sampler2d uniform but he never sent it to the shader.

Comment: @MaikKlein: Maybe you should stop trying to figure out what code is doing and [read an *actual tutorial* that explains this stuff](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the texture to a texture unit, e.g. unit 0:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

Add a `sampler2D` uniform to your shader:

```
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
```

Set the uniform to the number of the texture unit, as an integer:

```
glUseProgram(program);
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "myTexture");
glUniform1i(location, 0);
```

In the shader, use `texture2D` to sample it, e.g.:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(myTexture, texCoords);
```

The key thing to know is that `sampler2D` uniforms can be set as integers; setting it to 1 means to use the texture bound to `GL_TEXTURE1`, and so on. The uniform's value defaults to 0, and the active texture unit defaults to `GL_TEXTURE0`, so if you use only one texture unit, you don't even need to set the uniform.

Comment: Ah okay I think I understand sampler objects now. Code like this http://open.gl/content/code/c3_basic.txt totally confused me. Thanks a lot.